# Unsupported Media Type error when using json-patch in Ramone

Tags: c#, json, rest-client, json-patch

Update: I downloaded Ramone project, added it to my project and then ran the application again with debugger. The error is shown below:

public MediaTypeWriterRegistration GetWriter(Type t, MediaType mediaType)
{
...

CodecEntry entry = SelectWriters(t, mediaType).FirstOrDefault(); => this line throws error

...
}
Error occurs in CodecManager.cs. I am trying to figure out why it does not recognize json-patch media type. Could it be because writer is not being registered correctly? I am looking into it. If you figure out the problem, please let me know. Since you are the author of the library, it will be easier for you to figure out the issue. I will have to go through all the code files and methods to find the issue. Thanks!

I was excited to know that Ramone library supports json-patch operations but when I tried it, I got following error:

415- Unsupported Media Type

This is the same error that I get when I use RestSharp. I thought may be RestSharp does not support json-patch and errors out so I decided to try Ramone lib but I still get same error. Endpoint has no issues because when I try same command using Postman, it works but when I try it programmatically in C#, it throws unsupported media type error. Here is my code:

```
var authenticator = new TokenProvider("gfdsfdsfdsafdsafsadfsdrj5o97jgvegh", "sadfdsafdsafdsfgfdhgfhehrerhgJ");

JsonPatchDocument patch = new JsonPatchDocument<MetaData>();
patch.Add("/Resident2", "Boyle");
//patch.Replace("/Resident", "Boyle");

RSession = RamoneConfiguration.NewSession(new Uri("https://api.box.com"));
RSession.DefaultRequestMediaType = MediaType.ApplicationJson;
RSession.DefaultResponseMediaType = MediaType.ApplicationJson;

Ramone.Request ramonerequest = RSession.Bind("/2.0/files/323433290812/metadata");

ramonerequest.Header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticator.GetAccessToken(code).AccessToken);
//var ramoneresponse = ramonerequest.Patch(patch); //results in error: 405 - Method Not Allowed
var ramoneresponse = ramonerequest.Put(patch); //results in error: 415 - Unsupported Media Type

var responsebody = ramoneresponse.Body
```

Endpoint information is available here: http://developers.box.com/metadata-api

I used json-patch section in the following article as a reference:

http://elfisk.dk/Ramone/Documentation/Ramone.pdf

By the way I tried Patch() method (as shown in above ref. article) but that resulted in "Method not allowed" so I used Put() method which seems to work but then errors out because of json-patch operation.

Any help, guidance, tips in resolving this problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks much in advance.

-Sham

Answer (score 0):

The Box documentation says you should use PUT (which is quite a bit funny). The server even tells you that it doesn't support the HTTP PATCH method (405 Method Not Allowed) - so PUT it must be.

Now, you tell Ramone to use JSON all the time (RSession.DefaultRequestMediaType = MediaType.ApplicationJson), so you end up PUT'ing a JSON document to Box - where you should be PUT'ing a JSON-Patch document.

Drop the "RSession.DefaultRequestMediaType = MediaType.ApplicationJson" statement and send the patch document as JSON-Patch with the use of: ramonerequest.ContentType("application/json-patch+json").Put(...).

Comment: Hi Jorn, Thanks for answering. I have already tried ramonerequest.contenttype("application/json-patch+json") but it also resulted in an error (media type writer not found ...). Let me try it once more. I will post the results here. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Jorn,I just tried again using your suggestion but as I mentioned before, I got the "writer not found" error. Here is the complete error: Could not find a writer codec for 'application/json-patch+json' + Ramone.MediaTypes.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument`1[WebApplication1._Default+MetaData] ---- Any other ideas? This is surprising that Ramone throws this error because Json-patch is a supported media type as far as I know.

Comment: It seems Ramone library I added through nuget has some hardcoded paths. Ramone.Request.ContentType(string ContentType) line 37 points to a file that is missing in the library. I am just thinking if I download the source code and compile it locally, that may fix the issue. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Edited the question and added more description! Please see update in the question above! Thank you!

Comment: Update: I have made some more progress. I notice that Ramone defines media type as json-patch and NOT as json-patch+json. So when I pass content type as json-patch, it seems to work but then the error changes to "remote server did not recognize media type" and I understand that this happens because remote server expects the content type to be json-patch+json (which is the default as per the IETF RFC). So i assume If I somehow change content type in ramone to json-patch+json, it may start working. Again, keeping fingers crossed!!

Comment: I didn't know that the media type had changed! In http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902 is has become "application/json-patch+json" whereas an earlier version (which Ramone builds on) used "application/json-patch". Try setting RamoneConfiguration.UseStandardCodecs = false and register the JSON-Patch codec manually: session.Codecs.AddCodec<JsonPatchDocument, JsonPatchDocumentCodec>(new MediaType("application/json-patch+json"));